# Windows 10 Session Init takes too long

Tags: boot, windows-10

I recently installed Windows 10 on HP ProBook 4530s and after it automatically installed all the drivers, rebooted and all the subsequent boot-ups take up to 1:30 min even with fast boot on. What is puzzling me though, is that during the problematic boot phase, HDD and CPU are basically doing nothing at all.

I did a boot trace and it looks like LSM service is causing this problem but I don't know how to proceed further with my investigation.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: look into the generic events what takes too long. If you are unsure, zip the ETL and share it.

Comment: were you able to find the cause?